# How can i convert a .bag file to .pcd

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i used ubuntu 16 and wrote in terminal: rosrun pcl_ros bag_to_pcd <input_file.bag>  <output_directory>,
but i'm getting this error:

```
[ERROR] [1488830410.790465733]: [registerPublisher] Failed to contact master at [localhost:11311].  Retrying...
```

Furthermore i tried to change localhost with my ip with command: exportROS_MASTER_URI=http://X.X.X.X:11311/,
but nothing!

Please help,i have no idea how to achieve this conversion!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256393/how-can-i-convert-a-.bag-file-to-.pcd/) by [terminxd](https://answers.ros.org/users/29593/terminxd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-03-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error is right there:

> Failed to contact master

For `rosrun`, you need to start a ROS master Otherweise, no subscriptions etc. will work.
Simply open another terminal and type `roscore`.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2017-03-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [terminxd](https://answers.ros.org/users/29593/terminxd/) on 2017-03-08**:
I tried this and i'm getting this message:

Unable to contact my own server at [http://IP_OF_TURTLEBOT:37529/].

This usually means that the network is not configured properly.

A common cause is that the machine cannot ping itself.  Please check

for errors by running:
ping ip_of_turtlebot